# Fetch request stops working if I change route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, fetch

When I change route with `this.props.history.push("/");` while the component is fetching, the next route doesn't make the fetch request properly and gives a
`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` how do I debug this problem any tips?
Fetch example:

```
const data = {
      name: "generateToken",
      param: {
        email: "email",
        pass: "apikey"
      }
    };
    return fetch("http://localhost/streamingapp/api/", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(content => {
        if (content.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            apiToken: content.response.result.token
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: Not sure that has anything to do with your history push.  Rather, looks like the fetch you make is returning html and res.json is throwing to the catch.  Perhaps an issue in your route or response?

Comment: Is there anyway I can debug this?

Comment: console.table(res) before you res.json()

Comment: I tried and there is no difference in the response between the no error one and the error one.

Comment: I agree that seems like an error that would be generated from `res.json()` because it's typical of trying to parse data that isn't properly formatted JSON.

Comment: perhaps the content thenable?  i think you're on the right track now.  afaik should have nothing to do with your history push unless there's something resetting your variables or something on transition.

Comment: I have a sidebar which calls setState and then history.push maybe is that? the variable used in setState then gets used for the component in the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is wondering for the solution there was a problem on the api which made the response html. And for the fix i just implement an abortController like this to cancel the fetch request:

```
//init controller
 abortController = new window.AbortController();

//fetch example
fetch("http://my-app/newapi/", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      signal: this.abortController.signal
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            series: responseData.response.result,
            loading: false
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.name === "AbortError") return;
        this.setState({
          series: "There was an internal error retry later."
        });
        console.error(error);
      });

//other code
componentWillUnmount() {
   this.abortController.abort();
}
```